# Flattening the hierarchy structure in the pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have an excel file with 3 hierarchical levels of data captured in 2 columns.

```
  A          B          C
  X          nan       nan
  Y          value     nan
  nan        Z         SOMETHING
```

In the above example, hierarchy is managed within the columns A & B. X is the first level of hierarchy, Y is the second and Z is the third. I need to create a dataframe with these three levels in a single row(flattening) and with the value of column 3 as shown below

```
A   B   C  D
X   Y   Z  SOMTHING
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sample you have provided this would give the desired output.  Basically transposing, backfilling empty values, then slicing and concatenating to get the final result.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(
{'A': {0: 'X', 1: 'Y', 2: np.nan},
 'B': {0: np.nan, 1: 'value', 2: 'Z'},
 'C': {0: np.nan, 1: np.nan, 2: 'SOMETHING'}})

df = df.T.bfill()

df = pd.concat([df.iloc[:1,:3].reset_index(drop=True),
           df.iloc[-1:,-1:].reset_index(drop=True)],
          axis=1)
df.columns = ['A','B','C','D']
```

Output

```
   A  B  C          D
0  X  Y  Z  SOMETHING
```

Comment: Thanks Chris. This is working fine for a single record. However, with multiple rows its stopping at the first row. Having multiple rows in B column that should be mapped to X &Y from A column. How do I go about it?

Comment: Try asking a question with data more closely reflects your requirements.